# I signed an offer. Can I change my mind?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, contracts, california

I signed an offer letter for a job that will start later this year. Now I changed my mind, and I want to accept another job. My question is: **can I refuse a job after I signed an offer letter without any legal consequence?**

I read the offer I signed and I can't find anywhere any sentence that suggest that it is a binding contract, so I think that there are no problems. However, I'm wondering: is there any legal binding implied in the offer letter?

The job is in California.

Comment: Does the contract say when you must notify them before terminating it?

Comment: @Brandin: it's not a contract, it's a job offer. But, no: the relationship is at-will.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Can I reject an accepted offer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24225/can-i-reject-an-accepted-offer?rq=1). Country is irrelevant as the precise legal value of offer letters is well within the realm of the legal profession and therefore off-topic. **Both questions specifically ask for legal advice and are therefore off-topic.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to immediately quit anyway, I'm sure they would prefer that you contact them now and apologise, before they waste more money on you.

That's probably about as much damage control as you can hope to achieve.